# Is there any way to kill Mikul?

Tags: the-witcher

Last time I played I didn't realize (maybe I got caught in the story) but Mikul is really annoying. I could get over his various crimes.

> But the fact that he betrays you and lies so you can get arrested is unacceptable.

So... is there any way to get back and kill him?

Comment: Unrelated... is there any way to add spoiler tags in here?

Comment: Of course, just add >! at the beginning of your spoiler text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way you can kill him in the game.